# Aligning Array Output in Rich Text Box

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist, alignment

I am working on the same program as a previous question, but now I am having trouble aligning the output of my now-fixed program. I know some of it might look messed up, but somehow I  got it to work.

Whatever the case, the output is unaligned with my headings and doesn't look good. I cannot figure out how to fix this.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Convert

Public Class frmAll
'Declare Streamreader
Private objReader As StreamReader


'Declare arrays to hold the information
Private strNumber(24) As String
Private strName(24) As String
Private strSize(24) As String
Private decCost(24) As Integer




Private Sub frmAll_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Set objReader
    objReader = New StreamReader("products.csv")
    Call FillArray()
End Sub

Private Sub FillArray()
    'Declare variables and arrays

    Dim decCost(24, 1) As Decimal
    Dim strFields() As String
    Dim strRec As String
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim chrdelim As Char = ToChar(",")
    'Set strRec to read the lines

    strRec = objReader.ReadLine

    'Do while loop to fill array.
    Do While strRec <> Nothing
        strFields = strRec.Split(chrdelim)
        strNumber(intCount) = strFields(0)
        strName(intCount) = strFields(1)
        strSize(intCount) = strFields(2)
        decCost(intCount, 0) = ToDecimal(strFields(3))
        decCost(intCount, 1) = ToDecimal(strFields(4))
        'Set strRec to read the lines again
        strRec = objReader.ReadLine
        'increment the index
        intCount += 1
    Loop
    Call Calculate(decCost)
End Sub

Private Sub Calculate(ByVal numIn(,) As Decimal)
    'Define arrays to hold total cost
    Dim decRowTotal(24) As Decimal

    'Define variables to hold the counters for rows and columns
    Dim intR As Integer
    Dim intC As Integer

    'Calcualte total cost
    For intC = 0 To 1
        For intR = 0 To 24
            decRowTotal(intR) += numIn(intR, intC) * 1
        Next
    Next

    Call Output(numIn, decRowTotal)

End Sub

Private Sub Output(ByVal NumIn(,) As Decimal, ByVal RowTotalIn() As Decimal)
    Dim strOut As String

    Dim intR As Integer = 0
    Dim intC As Integer = 0

    strOut = "ID" & vbTab & "Item" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Size" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Total Price" &
        vbCrLf & "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" &
        vbCrLf

    For intC = 0 To 24
        strOut &= strNumber(intC) & vbTab
        strOut &= strName(intC) & vbTab
        strOut &= strSize(intC) & vbTab & vbTab
        strOut &= RowTotalIn(intC).ToString("c")
        strOut &= vbCrLf

    Next



    rtbAll.Text = strOut


End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Which font are you using in your richtextbox?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong tool for this kind of work.
You need a DataGridView instead of a RichTextBox.
With a DataGridView you can adjust the column size at your will.

The approach of using tabs to create pseudocolumns inside the richtextbox fails because, if some text (the item column for example) is longer than the space used to represent a tab, then the next tab will shift to a rightmost position and throughout the rest of the line the text is misaligned.
You can try to minimize the problem adding or removing tabs, but, unless the text pixel length equals the length reserved for your tabs, your columns will be misaligned.

In the link provided below you will find an example of a simple unbound datagridview filled with string data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3ce6k8(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It says in my assignment to put it in a RichTextBox and format columns. But I am unsure of how to do this without getting really deep into it, things we've not gotten to yet. If the words were relatively the same size, it'd be simple, but some are really long, others are short.

Comment: The situation requires some compromise. First use a Fixed Font  (FixedSys for example) then decide the length in char of your columns. Then truncate the strings longer than the column width at the column width less 3 chars, at the end add three points to indicate that the string was truncated